# How to make a div scroll without having to hover over that div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am developing a Single page website. In the second page, I have a scrollable div. But the div is scroll-able only when I put my mouse over it. I want to be scrollable all the time. And when the div finished scrolling, I want the page to continue scrolling.

I am using angular to do that, here is my code:

```
<style>
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
</style>

<div class="text-center element" vs-repeat="250" style="height:200px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
      <div ng-repeat="chat in chats" class="item">
           <h3 class="media-heading">{{chat.todo}}</h3>
      </div>

</div>
```

And here it is my function:

```
  $scope.scrollPos = 0;

        $window.onscroll = function(){
            $scope.scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
            $scope.$apply();
  }

}])
```

Comment: You could try with [scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) - it allows you to concatenate variuos scroll events. There is a demo site (Appliance Tec ltd) which alternate vertical scrolling with horizontal and again vertical.

Comment: I tried using that.But I could not get what I needed and I had hard time finding a proper example I can follow . Can you give me some hints how to use it